# LDA gensim. How to update a Postgres database with the correct topic number for every document?

Tags: python, postgresql, lda, gensim

I am taking different documents from a database and I check with LDA (gensim), what kind of latent topics are there in these documents. This works pretty well. What I would like to do is to save in the database for every document what is its most probable topic. And I am not sure what is the best solution for it. I could, for example, at the beginning extract a unique id of every document from the database together with the text_column and somehow process it that I know at the end which id belongs to which topic number. Or may be I should do it in the last part, where I print the documents and their topics. But I don't know how to connect it back to the database. By the comparison of the text_column with the document and assigning the corresponding topic number? Would be grateful for any comment.

```
stop = stopwords.words('english')

sql = """SELECT text_column FROM table where NULLIF(text_column, '') IS NOT NULL;"""
cur.execute(sql)
dbrows = cur.fetchall()
conn.commit()

documents = []
    for i in dbrows:
    documents = documents + list(i)

# remove all the words from the stoplist and tokenize
stoplist = stopwords.words('english')

additional_list = set("``;''".split(";"))

texts = [[word.lower() for word in document.split() if word.lower() not                 in stoplist and word not in string.punctuation and word.lower() not in additional_list] 
     for document in documents]

# remove words that appear less or equal of 2 times
all_tokens = sum(texts, [])
tokens_once = set(word for word in set(all_tokens) if all_tokens.count(word) <= 2)
texts = [[word for word in text if word not in tokens_once]
     for text in texts]

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
my_num_topics = 10

# lda itself
lda = ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=my_num_topics)
corpus_lda = lda[corpus]

# print the most contributing words for selected topics
for top in lda.show_topics(my_num_topics):
    print top

# print the most probable topic and the document
for l,t in izip(corpus_lda,documents):
    selected_topic = max(l,key=lambda item:item[1])
    if selected_topic[1] != 1/my_num_topics:
        selected_topic_number = selected_topic[0]
        print selected_topic
        print t
```

Comment: Normally you would select the PK together with the text from the database, like `SELECT id, text_column FROM table where ...`. In python you could then put the key->value pairs into a dict (with id as key) or in a set/array of 2-tuples.

Comment: Thank you! I was just overcomlicating things in my head. Worked perfectly with `documents.append(i)` in the first loop. The way I was doing it before (`documents = documents + list(i)`) was starting to split words on letters, when I was adding an id to the select query.

Comment: And this line is different, just in case somebody would need the code `texts = [[word.lower() for word in document[1].split() if word.lower() not in stoplist and word not in string.punctuation and word.lower() not in additional_list] 
         for document in documents]`

Answer (score 1):

As wildplasser has commented, I just had to select the id together with the text_column. I was trying it before, but with the way I was appending the data to the list, it was not suitable for the further processing. The code below works and as a result creates a table with the id and a number of the most probable topic.

```
stop = stopwords.words('english')

sql = """SELECT id, text_column FROM table where NULLIF(text_column, '') IS NOT NULL;"""
cur.execute(sql)
dbrows = cur.fetchall()
conn.commit()

documents = []
    for i in dbrows:
    documents.append(i)

# remove all the words from the stoplist and tokenize
stoplist = stopwords.words('english')

additional_list = set("``;''".split(";"))

texts = [[word.lower() for word in document[1].split() if word.lower() not                 in stoplist and word not in string.punctuation and word.lower() not in additional_list] 
 for document in documents]

# remove words that appear less or equal of 2 times
all_tokens = sum(texts, [])
tokens_once = set(word for word in set(all_tokens) if all_tokens.count(word) <= 2)
texts = [[word for word in text if word not in tokens_once]
 for text in texts]

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
my_num_topics = 10

# lda itself
lda = ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=my_num_topics)
corpus_lda = lda[corpus]

# print the most contributing words for selected topics
for top in lda.show_topics(my_num_topics):
    print top

# print the most probable topic and the document
lda_topics = []
for l,t in izip(corpus_lda,documents):
    selected_topic = max(l,key=lambda item:item[1])
    if selected_topic[1] != 1/my_num_topics:
        selected_topic_number = selected_topic[0]
        lda_topics.append((selected_topic[0],int(t[0])))

cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE table_topic (id bigint PRIMARY KEY, topic int);""")
for j in lda_topics:
    my_id = j[1]
    topic = j[0]
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO table_topic (id, topic) VALUES (%s, %s)", (my_id,topic))
    conn.commit()
```